# How tanh has to do with nonlinearity

Tags: nonlinear-system

I was reading an article about image processing and I came across `sigmoidal activation function` and `tanh` like in this article:

[image]

But I'm struggling to understand the concept behind the nonlinearity here and what has to do with `tanh`, could anyone clarify this idea, please

Comment: It seems like, in this text, "nonlinearity" is being used instead of "[nonlinear] function".

Comment: @MattiP. I couldn't add nonlinearity as a tag so I put nonlinear system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\psi(t)=\mathrm{tanh}(\alpha t)$ is a nonlinear transformation.

For $|\alpha t|$ close to $0$, the function is actually an approximately linear function of $t$, with $\psi(t) \approx \alpha t$.

By the time $|\alpha t| \ge 2$, the function's nonlinearity is very apparent, almost not really depending on $\alpha t$ at all, but just the sign of $\alpha t$, so $\psi(t) \approx \mathrm{sgn}(\alpha t)$.

In summary, $\psi(t)=\mathrm{tanh}(\alpha t)$ is a nonlinear tranformation with a "softer" transition than the basic $\psi(t)=\mathrm{sgn}(t)$ nonlinear transformation.

Comment: It seems logic what you said but why 2?

Comment: See the plots here: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tanh%28x%29

Comment: Okay I see: 2 depends on $\alpha$ but what does represents this value to tanh?

Comment: According to the excerpt, tanh() is used as part of a blob detector in images.  tanh() turns darker portions of an image into a -1, and lighter portions into a +1, so you can classify light regions and dark regions.  By using tanh() you can also classify regions that transition between light and dark.